# Is there a shorthand way to tell TypeScript that a variable is a number or undefined or null?

Tags: typescript

I find that a common pattern I use for variables is that it is a Number (or String), but before having any value, it can be `undefined` or `null`. So I can use

```
let s: string | null | undefined;
```

Is there a shorthand form to specify this? Or do I always need to specify the `| null | undefined` part?

Or perhaps because we tend to start with `null`:

```
let s: string | null = null;
```

so if there is a shorthand for `string | null`, that would work too.

Comment: You can make any type you use frequently into an alias, e.g. `type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined;`.

Comment: that sounds good, so it is like `let s: Maybe<string> = null;`? Is there a better name than `Maybe` and do some projects use a pretty standard name for it? `Maybe` sounds like it maybe... but it is more like 95% of the time it is `string`, but just to start with, it is `null`

Comment: You can call it whatever you want; `Nullable<T>` is a common name for this as it’s the opposite of the TS-provided `NonNullable<T>`